# Trying to load pickled data to a list isn't appending properly

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

I'm writing a to-do list application, and to store the class objects `task` I'm pickling a list of the objects created. However, when I load the data, the list appears empty. The way I structured it is to create an empty list each session, then append the contents of the pickle file. When new tasks are created, they are appended and the whole list is then appended and then reloaded.

This is my first real software project, so my code looks pretty rough. I reviewed it and can't find any glaring errors, but obviously I am doing something wrong.

Here is the relevant code:

```
import _pickle as pickle
import os.path
from os import path
from datetime import datetime

#checks if data exists, and creates file if it does not
if path.exists('./tasks.txt') != True:
    open("./tasks.txt", 'wb')
else:
    pass

#define class for tasks
class task:
    def __init__(self, name, due, category):
        self.name = name
        self.due = datetime.strptime(due, '%B %d %Y %I:%M%p')
        self.category = category
    def expand(self): # returns the contents of the task
        return str(self.name) + " is due in " + str((self.due - datetime.now()))

data = []
# load data to list
def load_data():
    with open('tasks.txt', 'rb') as file:
        while True:
            data = []
            try:
                data.append(pickle.load(file))
            except EOFError:
                break
...

# returns current task list
def list_tasks():
    clear()
    if not data:
        print("Nothing to see here.")
    else:
        i = 1
        for task in data:
            print("%s. %s" % (i, task.expand()))
            i = i+1

#define function to add tasks
def addTask(name, due, category):
    newTask = task(name, due, category)
    data.append(newTask)
    with open('./tasks.txt', 'wb') as file:
        pickle.dump(data, file)
    load_data()
    list_tasks()

...

load_data()
list_tasks()
startup()
ask()
```

Comment: What happens if you erase that `data = []` line inside your `while True:` loop?

Comment: @Kevin Ah, I see the problem now. But, I get this now: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/john/Developer/todo/main.py", line 77, in <module>
    list_tasks()
  File "/Users/john/Developer/todo/main.py", line 43, in list_tasks
    print("%s. %s" % (i, task.expand()))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'expand'```

Comment: Wild guess, but maybe changing the line from `data.append(pickle.load(file))` to `data.extend(pickle.load(file))` would help? Before testing that you might need to delete the `tasks.txt` file to make sure it doesn't have improperly-structured data.

Comment: @Kevin Worked! Answer and I'll check mark it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = []
# load data to list
def load_data():
    with open('tasks.txt', 'rb') as file:
        while True:
            data = []
            try:
                data.append(pickle.load(file))
            except EOFError:
                break
```

That second `data = []` doesn't look right. Having `data = []` both inside and outside of the function creates two `data` objects, and the one you're appending to won't be accessible anywhere else. And even if it was accessible, it would still be empty since it's being reset to `[]` in every iteration of the while loop. Try erasing the inner `data = []`. Then the `data.append` call will affect the globally visible `data`, and its contents won't be reset in each loop.

Additionally, going by the rest of your code it looks like that `data` is supposed to be a list of tasks. But if you pickle a list of tasks and then run `data.append(pickle.load(file))`, then `data` will be a list of lists of tasks instead. One way to keep things flat is to use `extend` instead of `append`.

```
data = []
# load data to list
def load_data():
    with open('tasks.txt', 'rb') as file:
        while True:
            try:
                data.extend(pickle.load(file))
            except EOFError:
                break
```

I think it may also be possible to load the data with a single `load` call, rather than many calls in a loop. It depends on whether your `tasks.txt` file is the result of a single `pickle.dump` call, or if you appended text to it multiple times with multiple `pickle.dump` calls while the file was opened in "append" mode.

```
def load_data():
    with open('tasks.txt', 'rb') as file:
        return pickle.load(file)
data = load_data()
```